# How to set Z-index in C# (winform apps)

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on desktop application in which i'm facing a problem on Z-Index. I generate some elements like `panel`, `picture box` and `labels` dynamically. My problem is in positioning element w.r.t z-Index, I tried `Bringtofront()` and `setChildIndex()` functions but they don't work as I wanted/expected.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to generate panel first and then generate child controls in it and for location of child control use relative positioning of panel.

above suggestion is just a normal way but still if your problem is different then please explain your problem in detail.

Answer (score -2):

Create panel dynamically then add controls to it:

```
Panel p = new Panel();
p.Controls.Add(controlobject);
```